# iTextSharp : display:none on the element not working when converting html to pdf

Tags: .net, itext

I am trying to convert the HTML in to PDF using iTextSharp 5.5.9. In my HTML, I have hide some element that is wrapped in a table, `div` and set the style `display:none;`. E.g.

```
< div style="display:none;">this should not show < /div>
```

The converted PDF shows all the elements and doesn't hide the hidden ones.

Does anyone has any workaround?

Comment: According to the [CSS conformance list](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm) (which I believe is still current) the `display` property is not supported.

Comment: so what is the alternative to hide the element in the html and convert it to pdf using iTextsharp so it won't render hidden elements ??

Comment: Do you got any solution for this issue? @Fayaz

Comment: don't actually remember dear but I think I have moved to evopdf library since it was well supported with .net

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, iTextSharp doesn't seem to support "visibility:hidden" either. I am testing evopdf right now and from their demos it seems that the visibility option is support (display:none; doesn't work there either)